# Strange Regex Issue

Tags: php, regex

I think I may have overlooked something here, but I'm not sure why this strange behaviour is occurring.

I know this is a nonsensical regex capture, but my question is why is this occurring.

```
<?php
// < 15 "a" characters returns "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa {" (no matches)
$code = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaa {';
// 15 "a" characters returns NULL
$code = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa {';

$code = preg_replace('#(a+)+\{#', 'b', $code);
var_dump($code);
?>
```

I realise that the regex has a `\s` missing. If I change the regex to `#(a+)+\s\{#` I get `"b"`. But why don't I get `"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa {"` with 15 "a" characters instead of a `NULL`? The manual states that `NULL` is returned when an error occurs, but nothing is being printed out by PHP (error checking is on).

**EDIT:**

The reason I am using `(a+)+` is because I am trying to simplify the problem down to the basic level. I started off with this:

I want to capture a series of non-whitespace characters followed by spaces followed by an opening brace.

```
this is some text {
```

So I used the regex:

```
#([^\s\{\}]+\s*)+\{#msi
```

Which also uses the double +. Is there a better way, and why is this causing an issue in the first place?

**EDIT 2**:
From the answers below, it appears that the double + causes a lot of backreferences and should be avoided. I have opted for this `[^\s\{\}][^\{\}]*+\{`.

Comment: The culprit has to be the strange `(a+)+` pattern -- why double the `+` quantifiers on the same pattern? Removing the second `+` should fix the issues.

Comment: Could you `var_dump(preg_last_error())`? I think the backtrack limit is reached due to the issues Jon mentioned (should the regex match the inner or the outer `+`?).

Comment: I works here BTW.... Backtrack limit=1,000,000

Comment: @Wrikken: you are right. My system is fine up to 17 'a' characters, but fails for anything longer. But `preg_last_error` is int(0)

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve but `b` is correct result for `#(a+)\s{#` expression

Comment: @Nazariy: that is not the point, the question is why NULL is returned.

Comment: @Borodin: I cannot get it to fail without having a non-zero return from `preg_last_error()`... What is your version? Because that would be a bug IMHO...

Comment: My apologies - my `var_dump` was in the wrong place in the code. I also get int(2) now that I have corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit',20000);
$code = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa {';
$code = preg_replace('#(a+)+\{#', 'b', $code);
var_dump($code, preg_last_error());

ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit',1000000);
$code = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa {';
$code = preg_replace('#(a+)+\{#', 'b', $code);
var_dump($code, preg_last_error());
```

Result:

```
NULL
int(2)
string(17) "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa {"
int(0)
```

But you really should use either `(a+)` or `(a)+`, not a combination of both.

Comment: So then it's running out of memory for backtracking. Not good. Would the greediness of + not capture all the "a" characters and stop there?

Comment: It's always good to see someone who employs regex with proper sense.

Comment: @AramKocharyan No. The greediness of the higher level statement `(a+)+` comes before that of the lower level `a+` statement.

Comment: So then does `(a+)` capture a single a, then `(a+)+` decides to continue and `(a+)` captures another a and so on?

Comment: The regex engine is as confused as you are, and tries about every permutation which would match. Hence the devastating amount of backtracks. It's not a memory issue, it's an setting which indicates 'if you need this amount of backtracks, something is probably not right'. I would like a feature in which the preg* functions actually emit an error though (warning or notice), instead of 'silently' failing.

Comment: If anybody could vote this bug (well, feature request) up: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51103